# Big O Rule Proof

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Give a mathematical definition of the order notation $f(n) \in \mathcal O(g(n))$ and explain how this concept relates to the algorithmic idea of worst case analvsis.

How do I go about answering this? It is a question from sample job interview questions...

Comment: What's wrong with the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)?

Comment: If you know the term Big O, you should know the definition at least right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is basically asking 'What does big-O mean?'.

[Wikipedia Big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

So $f(n)\leq Ag(n)$ for some constant $A$ as $n$ gets large.

Now if an algorithm takes $f(n)$ time to run for problem size $n$, $g(n)$ can be used to predict the worst case run-time within the bounds of the constant $A$. That is, $g(n)$ is of the right order (or more) for the complexity of the algorithm considered.

The reason for doing this is that $g(n)$ can probably be evaluated easily, but $f(n)$ can probably only be evaluated exactly by running the algorithm.

For example, for an implementation of the simple bubble sort algorithm, $f(n)$ can only be evaluated for particular data sets of size $n$ and determining the worst case would be hard. However, it can be shown that $g(n)=n^2$ is of the correct order and can be evaluated easily.

For an interview question, maybe you could show off by talking about related concepts such as $\Theta$ notation!